# jQuery draws to a halt on Chrome and mac OS

Tags: jquery

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/nWWSa/

```
var $lis = $('ul.innerfade > li');

function fadeThemOut()
{
    $lis.fadeOut('slow', fadeThemIn);
}

function fadeThemIn()
{
    $lis.fadeIn('slow', fadeThemOut);
}

// kick it off
fadeThemOut();
```

The fading in/out works fine a couple of times, but then starts going *very* slow. What is the problem? Is this a bug?

Comment: Note to self, stop answering SO questions while sleep-deprived. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459654/create-an-endless-loop-in-jquery/7459666#7459666 Thanks for asking this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the callbacks are executed for *each* element once it is faded in/out, not only when all of them are. So this accumulates a lot of callbacks. It goes like this (lets say we have only two elements, A and B):

At the beginning, the queues are empty:
A: `[]`
B: `[]`

Then you call `fadeOut` on both elements:
A: `[fadeOut]`
B: `[fadeOut]`

A fades out: `fadeIn` is added to both elements.
A: `[fadeIn]`
B: `[fadeOut, fadeIn]`

Then B fades out:  Again, `fadeIn` is added to both elements.
A: `[fadeIn, fadeIn]`
B: `[fadeIn, fadeIn]`

A fades in:  `fadeOut` is added to both elements.
A: `[fadeIn, fadeOut]`
B: `[fadeIn, fadeIn, fadeOut]`

B fades in:  ...
A: `[fadeIn, fadeOut, fadeOut]`
B: `[fadeIn, fadeOut, fadeOut]`

And so forth. The exact order might differ, but as animations are queued by default, this adds more and more callbacks to the queue.

You can solve this using *deferred objects*:

```
$.when($lis.fadeOut('slow')).then(fadeThemIn);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nWWSa/2/)

Now, `fadeThemIn` is only called when the animation of all elements is completed.

---

Another way would be to change the functions to not work on all elements, but only on the current one:

```
var $lis = $('ul.innerfade > li');

function fadeThemOut()
{
    $(this).fadeOut('slow', fadeThemIn);
}

function fadeThemIn()
{
    $(this).fadeIn('slow', fadeThemOut);
}

// kick it off
fadeThemOut.call($lis);
```

though it could be that the elements are not in sync then.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nWWSa/3/)

In your specific case, you could just fade in and out the `ul` element.

Comment: Could I merge both solutions? (I.e. use deferred objects *and* work only on the current element?)

Comment: I guess so, but there is no reason to do so. `$(this).fadeOut(foo)` is basically the same as `$.when($(this).fadeOut()).then(foo)`. I think using deferred objects only would be the better way. Or just perform the animation on the parent element (if possible).

Answer (score 4):

Your code is EXTREMELY ineffective. It basically calls fadeout on all the elements, and then calls fadein on all elements, one time for each element, etc etc. This essentially creates a forkbomb, and before long the function is running millions of times in memory, since the amount of calls quadruples every time.

Here's a more effective way of doing it: http://jsfiddle.net/bVj3X/

Comment: It's not a fork bomb. And your fiddle is doing a separate fade on each `li` which means more browser redraws. Doing on less dom elements such as a parent element would be more performant.

Comment: how you call it then? each fadein and each fadeout, nubmer of action is multiplied by 4.

Comment: Why am I not reaching the call stack limit even with one `li`? Even with just one `li` the call stack should grow arbitrarily large, right?

Comment: @Randomblue: No, if you have only one `li`, then `$li` would be the same as `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

First up, I would suggest that if you were trying to do this, do it on as little elements as possible.  The more elements you perform this on, the more browser redraws happen.  Currently, your fiddle is doing this on 4 elements, try doing it on 1 element.  This way, your browser will be calculating one redraw at a time, instead of 4 (semi-)concurrently.

Change your `$lis` variable to:

```
var $lis = $('ul.innerfade');
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nWWSa/1/)